# Cant use a react-leaflet map as a webview in react-native

Tags: webview, react-native-webview

So, I have this project in react which is a map made with react leaflet and I'm trying to call it as a webview inside react-native, but its not working, it apears all blank [webview called with react-leaflet on in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCxdK.png)

And its not the webview problem, beacause I can call other websites inside of it

Here I just changed the url to a youtube page
[webview called of youtube page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShZxO.png)

here's my code `import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

import {Container, mapurl} from './styles';

```
export function WebViewComponent() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: mapurl,
        }}
      />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

`
Here is the leaftlet page that i'm trying to call, I made a deploy on vercel
https://map-webview-test-4xfd.vercel.app/

Comment: Hello man, have you discovered how to make this works?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution but I am also using a LeafLet map from a WebView, I had this display problem for the map and I was able to solve it by adding the field originWhitelist when calling, if that helps great.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <WebView 
    originWhitelist={['your url']}
    startInLoadingState
    renderLoading={
      () => (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        </View>
      )
    }
    source={{ uri: your url }}
  />
</View>
```